# How to ignore text between quotes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages, regular-language, transpiler

I make my own language in JavaScript using regular expression. How can you recommend to ignore text in string variables?

for example, my code:

```
if (flag) {
    print("Yes")
} elif (!flag) {
    print("Elif is worked")
}
```

will transpile to

```
if (flag) {
    console.log("Yes")
} else if (!flag) {
    console.log("else if is worked")
}
```

I want to ignore text in quotes:

```
if (flag) {
    console.log("Yes")
} else if (!flag) {
    console.log("elif is worked")
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "ignore" ? Do you want to replace the texts with string variables ?

Comment: I dont want to replace my features. For example "elif" converts to "else if". I don't want to change it in string variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without wanting to discourage you: Don't use regular expressions, because the problem domain is too complex for them to work properly. Instead, implement a tokenizer and a parser. But generally speaking, this topic is too broad to be answered here.

There is a tutorial online [here](http://lisperator.net/pltut/) which shows how to implement a programming language in javascript.